# How to set marker Z-index on MapBox Android?

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-marker

My app shows a user marker. Basically, the user marker shows where the current user is on the map but I also have other markers placed on the map. In the end, it covers up my user marker. I want my User Marker to be on the top of the map. I want it to be rendered last so it shows on the very top.

Any idea?

Comment: do you find the solution for your problem?

Comment: @PhanVanLinh, unfortunately no. There is no way to control this unless otherwise you implement your own Marker which is possible via ViewMarkerOptions which implements a view I think, there are other cool options there like anchor, offset, etc. Can't remember if it has z-ordering. Can't believe this basic stuff in 2D rendering was left out which is a shame really. I can't go down ViewMarkerOptions though, the map becomes so slow if you have hundreds of them. I think the best option would be the Mapbox Studio, I haven't tried it though.

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone is looking for a newer answer for latest SDKs.

Mapbox Marker class is now deprecated in newer versions of Mapbox Android SDK. [Annotations](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/tree/master/plugin-annotation) plugin is suggested instead, which has a Symbol class for markers.

In *mapbox-android-plugin-annotation-v7* library Symbol class had a `withZIndex()` method which allowed to manipulate Z-ordering of map objects.

In *mapbox-android-plugin-annotation-v8* this method was renamed to `withSymbolSortKey()` (which was a bit tricky to find and discover).

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution from here https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/pull/5294

If you use `MarkerView`, you can bring your marker to the very top with `MarkerViewManager#select` call.

```
mapboxMap.getMarkerViewManager().select(marker);
```

It will end by calling `View#bringToFront` from Android View API, the selected marker view will show on top of all other marker views.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may help:

[Mapbox Android SDK: Bring marker to front](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38153574/mapbox-android-sdk-bring-marker-to-front)

> Yes. Starting with Mapbox Android SDK v4.1, the selected marker will
>   come to front.
>
> You can select a marker with `mapboxMap.selectMarker(marker);`